# Split string with delimiter while checking for delimiter

Tags: c#, string, split

How can I split a string based on a custom delimiter while also ensuring that the string ends with a delimiter? I am trying to process incoming client data and trying to divide up the messages. But it is possible that the client sends the server a message that is comprised of 3 smaller messages, where the third message is not yet complete. ie it does not contain the delimiter, meaning more is to come.

Example

```
using System;

public class Test{
    private string eofString = "<EOF>";
    private string[] eofArray = { "<EOF>" };


    public void Main(){
        string foo = "bob<EOF>jill<EOF>jake";
        string[] splitMessages = foo.Split(eofArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for(int i = 0; i < splitMessages.Length; i++){
            Console.WriteLine(splitMessages[i]);
        }       
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
bob
jill
jake
```

My expected output is

```
bob
jill
```

because the end of the string `foo` did not end with `<EOF>`.

Which is wrong. I want to put `jake` in this case back into a string builder.

Comment: Question is not very clear. Can u show whats your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if string ends with the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can split with this pattern:

```
"<EOF>([^\<]*)"
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. This is especially true of regexen, which are notorious for being opaque line noise to most.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a regex based solution the following will work as well.

```
string input = "bob<EOF>jill<EOF>jake";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<message>.+?)\<EOF\>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
IEnumerable<string> messages = r.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select(i => i.Groups["message"].Value);
```

Basically it is using a non-greedy match pattern `.+?` (1 or more of any character, matching as few characters as possible) within a named captured group `(?<message> #pattern goes here)` that must be terminated with the fixed string `<EOF>`.  All of the matches are found in one "pass" and just need to be projected out of the match collection by the name of the capture group.